# Which approach I should follow; SharePoint business connectivity services OR developing SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, bcs, app

I have developed a document management system and an enterprise wiki library for our company using SP2013. The second project I am going to start is to develop an asset management system for our company. Currently we have 5 small separate systems and some excel sheets for managing our assists ( PCs, server, VM, vehicles, equipment, etc..).
The general requirements for the new assets management system are:-

1. To create relationship between our assets which are managed in 5 separated systems. For example using the new system we can know for each server how many VM are there and what type of equipment’s are related to each server. Where currently there is no system for managing this relation, and we are using excel sheet to manage these relations.
2. To insert certain info about maintaining server, pc, vehicles in the new assets management system, so it should have its own database also.
3. Users that are inside our active directory will have different permission and privileges on the new system.

So as SharePoint is our main system and we already have running application inside it(document management & enterprise wiki ), so I have the following three main approaches to follow for developing our assets management system:-

1. Is to create BCS inside SharePoint that perform CRUD operation and other functionalities  on the external system databases.
2. To develop an asp.net mvc web application and deploy it  a Auto-hosted App inside SharePoint.
3. To create a separate web application outside SharePoint and just have hyperlinking to navigate between SharePoint and the assets management ?

Personally I prefer using the second approach as it will give me more flexibility in dealing with the system and also to be able to define our own databases database, and also the system can be accesses as a SharePoint site.
So what approach I should follow, and is there another approach I should consider?
BR

Answer (score 1):

2 does indeed give you more control, but also gives you more risk if this service has to be externally facing.

BCS is fine for simple tasks, but if you need the control go for 2, but make sure you look at any and all security concerns first.

To recommend another course of action a topology diagram would have to be supplied to ascertain the actual flow of data and where and how it is needed to be accessed. However with almost any case like this a custom web app and or service is the usual route for compatibility, performance and control as long as I have stated it is secure enough.